# Razzle-Dazzle and success vs Blindness

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e

[Razzle-Dazzle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1417) increases the duration of blindned or dazzled condition:

> Extend the duration of the blinded or dazzled condition you give the target **by 1 round**.

[Blindness](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=26) blinds also on a Success:

> Success: The target is blinded **until its next turn begins**.

How do these two interact?
Options:

1. "until its next turn begins" is not a duration measurable in rounds, so it is unchanged
2. the target is blinded until the beginning of its second turn
3. other

Comment: This question is being discussed [on Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11565)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it is 2, but cannot prove it conclusively (hence comment not answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Blinded until beginning of its second turn

There is no necessary minimum duration that [Razzle-Dazzle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1417) mentions. Normally, the Blindness condition would expire at the start of the targets turn. From the [Start of Turn](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=436) rules:

> If you created an effect lasting for a certain number of rounds, reduce the number of rounds remaining by 1. The effect ends if the duration is reduced to 0.

So a normal Blindness would have a round duration of "1" that expires at the start of the targets turn. Razzle-Dazzle, as it mentions, would extend this duration by 1 round, so it would be option 2 (the Blindness condition would expire at the start of the target's second turn).

Not even the [Duration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=351) rules mention any special cases for extending things that expire at the start of a creature's turn. So Razzle-Dazzle would behave normally.